# Check image dimensions before uploading in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I'd like to check that an image is less than 512x512 before uploading it for the avatar.

I have the  element that selects it and i can upload that just fine. But i'd like to make sure the dimensions are correct before sending it up to the server.

I've done some googling but I cannot find a nextJS solution. I would prefer not to use their Image component because it seems overkill for just checking dimensions? What is the simplest way (even if using their component)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should **always** use the Next.js `<Image />`component when possible, it ensures your images are optimized and displayed without any layout shift.

```
interface ImageSize {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export function getImageSize(file: File): Promise<ImageSize> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    image.onload = () => {
      resolve({ width: image.width, height: image.height });
    };
  });
}
```

However if the image you want to check is an instance of the `File` object type you can implement the following function returning a promise with the dimensions as an object.

Comment: I will try this out. Not sure why i need to "always" use the Image component if i'm not keeping it around. I'm only loading it to check the dimensions then it doesn't get used again.  Seems I would want the simplest component that could do that job with the least amount of overhead.

Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisValentine You are absolutely right, if you do not need to display the images the `<Image />` component is of no use to you. Please not that the example I provided uses the browsers `Image` object, and not the component by the same name.

Answer (score 0):

`<Image />` has built in props to check sizes `onLoad` etc :

```
'use client'

<Image onLoadingComplete={(img) => console.log(img.naturalWidth)} />
```

[Image documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#onloadingcomplete)

As I understand, you need to check the image dimension to adapt your design.

Instead of this approach, I recommend you to adapt your image to design and not design to your image. You can set specific set of dimensions, here is example:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Page() {
 return (
  <div className="grid-element">
    <Image
      fill
      src="/example.png"
      sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
    />
  </div>
 )
}
```

For your avatar purpose, you don't need to check image size (or block upload client-side), all you need is to download the image and set `width={512}` and `height={512}` props on the page. If you use some media platforms to store your images as [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), you can "crop" image on load.

P.S. I know that setting Images in next is tricky and not trivial, but it's strongly recommended to use native props and solutions for page optimization.

P.S 2. You can share your code we can help you.

Comment: I dont need to adapt to the size. i just need to make sure the uploaded image is not dimensionally larger than i want to accept.

Comment: So you need to get width and height in your middleware instead of frontend. Share your code of upload or uploadHandler at frontend.